# SIP Registration Issue

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, sip

I am currently working on SIP sample application.

I am trying to do the registration using C based Socket programming on Unix. I have been successfully being able to get register with PJSIP, but when the same parameters I am sending with normal socket programming, then I am not being able to receive any response from server.

Here is the source code:

```
char *server = (char *)serverAddress; // First arg: server address/name
char *echoString = "Request msg REGISTER/cseq=46476 (tdta0x8857200)\r\nREGISTER sip:DOMAIN_NAME SIP/2.0\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.120:51648;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwEt4VvIVdjIJKRmEJbkidYDAu-zQbIqv\r\nMax-Forwards: 70\r\nFrom: <sip:USER_NAME@DOMAIN_NAME>;tag=epCBN7JXsQE1nnI5d5SOZe9a5ujRyI67\r\nTo: <sip:USER_NAME@DOMAIN_NAME>\r\nCall-ID: .5yYCqh2jEYdy5T4kxhzxwDYEkCO1XlD\r\nCSeq: 46476 REGISTER\r\nContact: <sip:USER_NAME@192.168.1.120:51648;ob>\r\nExpires: 300\r\nAllow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS\r\nAuthorization: Digest username=\"USER_NAME\", realm=\"asterisk\", nonce=\"3b63254c\", uri=\"sip:DOMAIN_NAME\", response=\"9e8fc78829d143a58fba5a79f6ad44fd\", algorithm=MD5\r\nContent-Length:  0"; 


size_t echoStringLen = strlen(echoString);


// Third arg (optional): server port/service
char *servPort = (char *)service;

// Tell the system what kind(s) of address info we want
struct addrinfo addrCriteria;                      // Criteria for address match
memset(&addrCriteria, 0, sizeof(addrCriteria));    // Zero out structure
addrCriteria.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;                // For the following fields, a zero value means 
                                                   // Any address family "don't care"


addrCriteria.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; // Only datagram sockets
addrCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;         // Only UDP protocol
// Get address(es)
struct addrinfo *servAddr; // List of server addresses
int rtnVal = getaddrinfo(server, servPort, &addrCriteria, &servAddr);
if (rtnVal != 0)
    DieWithUserMessage("getaddrinfo() failed", gai_strerror(rtnVal));
// Create a datagram/UDP socket
int sock = socket(servAddr->ai_family, servAddr->ai_socktype,
                  servAddr->ai_protocol); // Socket descriptor for client
if (sock < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("socket() failed");
// Send the string to the server
ssize_t numBytes = sendto(sock, echoString, echoStringLen, 0,
                          servAddr->ai_addr, servAddr->ai_addrlen);
if (numBytes < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("sendto() failed");
else if (numBytes != echoStringLen)
    DieWithUserMessage("sendto() error", "sent unexpected number of bytes");
// Receive a response
struct sockaddr_storage fromAddr; // Source address of server
// Set length of from address structure (in-out parameter)
socklen_t fromAddrLen = sizeof(fromAddr);
char buffer[100 + 1]; // I/O buffer
numBytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 100, 0,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromAddrLen);
if (numBytes < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("recvfrom() failed");
else if (numBytes != 100)
    DieWithUserMessage("recvfrom() error", "received unexpected number of bytes");
// Verify reception from expected source

int value = SockAddrsEqual(servAddr->ai_addr, (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr);
if (value == 0)
    DieWithUserMessage("recvfrom()", "received a packet from unknown source");
freeaddrinfo(servAddr);
buffer[echoStringLen] = '\0';     // Null-terminate received data
printf("Received: %s\n", buffer); // Print the echoed string

close(sock);
exit(0);
```

When I am trying to debug the code, then the breakpoint gets disappeared from recvfrom method call as follows.

```
numBytes = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 100, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromAddrLen);
```

Thanks in advance for your co-operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "the breakpoint gets disappeared"? Is your program crashing at that line? As far as the SIP side of things goes the approach you are using will never work since you are attempting to replay an existing REGISTER request. The server will reject a replayed request for a number of reasons including being a duplicate SIP transaction and using a stale nonce.

Comment: The application is neither crashing nor is moving forward. It seems like, the app is waiting for the server to respond for recv method.But using other Softphones, I have been able to get registered many times. Since the SIP registration is valid for some time interval and after that it is getting un-registered. For maintaining the session, we are require to get re-registered with SIP Servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting a response from the Registrar server it's most likely because it couldn't understand the REGISTER request you sent it or rejected it as a duplicate. More that likely you will need to get a bit more sophisticated about how you are constructing your REGISTER request rather than simply sending a hard coded string.

Apart from that one obvious thing you could try is to add the required \r\n\r\n onto the end of your echoString. All SIP requests are required to end the header portion with a double line break and that is missing from your string.

Answer (score 0):

`recvfrom()` blocks until a response is received, unless you set the socket to non-blocking.  A better approach would be to use `select()` with a timeout (like a second or two).  Better still would be to then put the entire thing into a loop which retries some number of times (like three or four).

Remember that UDP makes no guarantees that your datagram will be delivered: it is entirely up to you to decide when you've waited long enough and need to try again.

Also, check that the values being set in `servAddr` by `getaddrinfo()` make sense.  If the address or port number is wrong, your packet may silently disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you confirm that this is socket issue then good to trace.

But if you are not sure then for this kind of issue use network analyze application (wireshark) & see the packet you send & receive. Then look into socket issue.